# Calculate a confidence interval for $\lambda$ based on a pivot.

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a sample from the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Calculate a confidence interval for $\lambda$ based on a suitable pivot.

My first idea was to look at $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$, because this is a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $n$ and scale parameter $1/\lambda$. If you choose $\lambda X_i$ instead of $X_i$, you will get a Gamma distribution with shape parameter $n$ and scale parameter $1$. This is a pivot, that we can use to answer this question. But now that I've found the pivot, I don't know how to use it to find the confidence interval. Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you know about critical values?

Comment: Is it $\xi_{1-\alpha/2}$? I dont really know.

Answer (score 0):

You want some sensible interval from your $\textrm{Gamma}(n,1)$ distribution which covers the desired probability $(1-\alpha)$.  Suppose this is $[u,v]$.

Then you argue $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda X_i$ will fall in this interval when $u \le \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda X_i \le v$, i.e. when $\frac{u}{\sum_{i=1}^n  X_i} \le  \lambda  \le \frac{v}{\sum_{i=1}^n  X_i} $, and so this gives a $(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval for $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have one more question : Do we know what $u,v$ are in terms of $\alpha$?

Comment: It depends on what you are looking for in a confidence interval beyond coverage of $(1-\alpha)$. Suppose $n=10$ and $\alpha=0.05$; then using R and `qgamma(0.025,10,1)` and  `qgamma(0.975,10,1)` would give about $[4.8,17.1]$, but there are other possibilities such as the narrower $[4.29,16.31]$ which takes advantage of the asymmetry of the distribution.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much for your help!